# Sort file list in ascending order of file size android for API 9

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have been successful in sorting Arraylist of files using the following code :

```
Comparator<File> stringLengthComparator = new Comparator<File>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                                            return Integer.compare((int) (o1.length() / 1000),
                                                    (int) (o2.length() / 1000));
                                        }
                                    };

                                    Collections.sort(flLst, stringLengthComparator);
```

This sorts the file list i.e. flLst, but the only issue is the above code requires API level 19 and above and my current API minimum requirement is  API level 9. I tried the following but I am unable to swap files :

```
for(x=0;x<flLst.size();x++)
                                        val1=flLst.get(x);
                                    for(x=0;x<flLst.size();x++)
                                    {
                                        for(int j=i;j<flLst.size();j++)
                                        {
                                            if(val1.length()>flLst.get(j).length())
                                            {
                                                temp=val1;
                                                val1=flLst.get(j);
                                                flLst.get(j)=temp;  // I get issue here as swapping file variables is not allowed this way
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
```

Is there a solution for API level 9 that I can use.

Comment: `Collections.sort()` has been around [since API Level 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E)).

Comment: Collections.sort() is not the problem. The problem is with Integer.compare() which is not supported below API 19. @CommonsWare

Comment: there are "problems", and problems...

Comment: Use Double.compare() instead of Integer.compare()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs, Integer's [compare()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) method:

> Compares two int values numerically. The value returned is identical
>   to what would be returned by:
>
> ```
> Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(y))
> ```

So in your case, try the following instead which was added in API level 1:

```
Comparator<File> stringLengthComparator = new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf((int) (o1.length() / 1000)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf((int) (o2.length() / 1000)));
    }
};
```

Comment: No need to divide both numbers by 1000.  Also no need to use compareTo, just subtract the two values.  If a>b, a-b >0.  if a<b, a-b < 0.  If a == b, a-b ==0.  Also, your algorithm needlessly breaks if the file is greater than MAX_INT (2 GB).

Answer (score 0):

```
Comparator<File> stringLengthComparator = new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        return o1.length() - o2.length();
    }
};
```

Your solution was just making things way overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and easy compare **by size**:

```
        Arrays.sort(fileList, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return Long.compare(f1.length(), f2.length());
                // For descending
                // return -Long.compare(f1.length(), f2.length());
            }
        });
```